# Using save_model to save the current user

Tags: python, django

I try to save the current user with creating the new object in the post_save. There is the model

```
class SourceHistory(models.Model):
    source = models.ForeignKey(Source, verbose_name=u'Источник', null=False, blank=False)
    editor = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=u'Пользователь', null=True, blank=True)
```

And in the admin.py

```
@admin.register(SourceHistory)
class SourceHistoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('source', 'editor')

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.editor = request.user
        obj.save()
```

And the creating a new object

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Source)
def source_save_history(sender, **kwargs):
    source = kwargs.get('instance')
    for f in source.memorized_fields:
        if source.__getattribute__(f) != source.memorized_fields[f]:
            sh = SourceHistory.objects.create(
                source=source
            )
```

So, using this way the 'editor' field in the new object is empty. How should I create the SourceHistory object with the current user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this in post_save(), user can only be determined in request

Comment: oh :( is there a way how I can save the current user without the request?

Comment: you need to do this in the view. Or, override the `save` method of `Source` model, to create a `SourceHistory` and provide `User` instance in `kwargs` of `save` method.